# SQL insert muliple records based on value in VB Form

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Basic Form with input fields that will generate a serial number for a single part and write it back to the SQL Database. How can I generate multiple serials based on a quantity field within the vb form?

SQL DB:

```
create table serialnumbers (
    serial int IDENTITY(10000,1),
    workorder varchar(50),
    partnumber varchar(50),
    employeeid int,
    [day] varchar(50)
)
```

VB:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Public Sub ClearTextBoxes(frm As Form)

    For Each Control In frm.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is TextBox Then
            Control.Text = ""     'Clear all text'
        End If
    Next Control

End Sub


Private Sub BTNSUBMIT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNSUBMIT.Click
    datetime.Text = Date.Now.ToString
    If workorder.Text = "" Or partnumber.Text = "" Or employeeid.Text = "" Or quantity.Text = "" Or datetime.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter All Required Fields")
    Else

        Try
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into famem1 Values ('" & workorder.Text & "', '" & partnumber.Text & "', '" & employeeid.Text & "', '" & datetime.Text & "') "

            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Successfully Added", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "add")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
        Call ClearTextBoxes(Me)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand, and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ You also should wrap your connection and command objects in USING statement so you can release the connections back to the connection pool.

Comment: As for the question at hand I am not entirely sure what you want. Are you wanting to create a certain number of identical rows based on user input?

Comment: Yes. The hope is that the user would input a quantity number on the form and it will write that number of rows to SQL.

Comment: You could use a tally table with a cross join pretty easily. But why do you want to have duplicate rows in your table? Sounds like something is a bit off there.

Comment: Currently the user inputs the work order, part number and employee id. All three are written to the database and the serial column auto increments for each insert. This only allows the creation of one serial number at a time. We would like to add a quantity field in the VB form that can be used to create multiple serials when inserting to SQL. Would a tally table help accomplish this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Are you wanting to receive multiple work order, partnumbers and employee ids all at one time?

Comment: Yes. Those are all the same each time the form is used. The serial column in the sql database auto increments a unique id for each insert. I need a way to write multiple records at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your insert procedure in a loop:

```
For a = 1 to 20 'or whatever qty the user inputs

    Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

            con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                   "Data Source = " & auth_path

            Dim sqlcommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

            'set work order number
            'set part number
            'set employee id

            'generate serial here

            con.Open()

            With sqlcommand
                .CommandText = "Insert Into ..... "
                .Connection = con
                .ExecuteNonQuery()

            End With

    End Using



Next
```

Or you could add a few fields to your database such as serial_1, serial_2 etc.

And then based on the qty your could update those fields with an IF Then statement.

```
If Cint(txt_qty.text) >= 2 Then

 .... ' update the record with serial_2

End If

If Cint(txt_qty.text) >= 3 Then

 .... ' update the record with serial_3

End If
```

Comment: Thank you but the first scenario still only writes one record to SQL. The second scenario will not work as the serial needs to auto generate.

Comment: I updated my answer to better demonstrate what I mean, although it is using a slightly different database provider, but you should understand what I am trying to show you

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. The code does work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @dustinw Do not forget to upvote or accept the answer that helps you.

Comment: While this works I would prefer to get rid of the loop. If this is a purely sql solution you could pass in the quantity and use a tally table. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/